# Avoid Timeout to read 18000 document on Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My Firestore contains 17500 documents.
It's a list of tokens, in order to send push notifications.

[image: Firestore database]

I stock these data in a dictionary, to be able to use them later:
`users = {"fr":[token, token], "en":[token, token]....}`

My code:

```
async function getAllUsers() {

    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();

    var users= {};

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {

        const userId = doc.id;

        var lang = doc.data().language

         if (!(lang in users)) {

            users[lang] = [];
            users[lang].push(doc.data().token);

         } else {
            users[lang].push(doc.data().token);
         }

    });

    return users;
}
```

My code doesn't work anymore. I get a timeout during the foreach loop.

Is it because I have too many documents?
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what exactly is timing out, but there are a couple things you should be aware of.

- You certainly can get errors if you attempt to read too many documents in one query.  The alternative to this is to use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to read the documents in smaller batches so that you don't exceed any query limits.
- By default Cloud Functions assumes a 60 second timeout on any function invocations.  If you need more than that, you can [increase the timeout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation), but you can only go up to 9 minutes.  After that, you have to split your work up among multiple function invocations.